# When does $ax+by+c=0$ represents a family of straight lines passing through a fixed point?

Tags: analytic-geometry

a first degree linear equation $ax+by+c=0$ represents a family of straight lines passing through a fixed point if and only if there is linear relationship between a,b and c? 
How can we prove this? Can the relation between a,b,c be a quadratic one or cubic one and so on or does it always have to be linear and why?

I tried to take any relation between a,b,c and put it in the equation of line but it turns out nothing can be said about whether it represents a family of lines or not?

Comment: No -- the equation $ax+by+c=0$ represents _one line_ somewhere in the plane. (Which line it is depends on what $a$, $b$ and $c$ are).

Comment: the equation ax+by+c = 0 has two unknown constants once a relationship between a,b,c is known then we are left with one unknown constant and equation with one unknown constant always  represents a family of lines.

Comment: x @Raghav: What do you mean by "has two unknown constants"? Is there a secret context to your question that you're too lazy to actually explain in the question and instead expect a reader to figure out telepathically?

Comment: ax+by+c=0 can be written as a/cx+b/cy+1=0 or Ax+By+1=0 where A,B are two unknown constants

Comment: What if $c=0$? :-P.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I don't understand the confusion or the 'tude here.  $ax +by + c = 0$ can be viewed as representing a family, just like $x^2 + C$ (as in $\int 2x \, dx = x^2 + C$) represents a family.  OP is asking for help in verifying that all members of the family $ax+by+c = 0$ pass through a fixed point if and only if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are linearly related to each other.  I feel like I'm just repeating OP but I don't know how it can be made more clear.

Comment: if c=0 then the equation is ax+by = 0 which already has only two unknown constants

Comment: Do not forget that we must have $(a,b) \ne (0,0)$ in order for the equation $ax+by+c=0$ to represent a line. (If both $a$ and $b$ are zero, we no longer have an equation of first degree, and in that case the solution is either all points (entire plane) or no points (empty set).)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Suppose, for example, that the fixed point is $(2,3)$.  Then **no matter what the values** of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are, the equation $2a + 3b = c$ is always true.  This is a linear relationship between $a$, $b$, and $c$.

And note that there's nothing special about the point $(2,3)$.  I just chose it to have a concrete example to explain the concept.  You can run through the exact same argument and use $(x_0, y_0)$ to represent the coordinates of an arbitrary fixed point.  This will basically give you one direction of the proof.  Technically both directions if you're careful with how you choose your words.

Comment: yeah now i understand thanks it helped.